# Pause and resume running mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got quite slow query (actually this is data loading from mysql.dump). Now I want to check how many rows are already loaded.

```
select count(*) from my_table;
```

As far as data is loading, `my_table` is locked, so I can't execute this sql before dump is loaded.

```
Cmd       ID   State               User   Host           DB      Time   Query                           
Query     191  update              root   localhost      rehub   00:09  INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ...
Query     189  Waiting for table   root   localhost      rehub   06:25  select count(*) from my_table
```

So is there a way to pause query 191, execute query 189 and then resume query 191?

Comment: my guess you can try your luck on the information_schame.tables ?

Comment: Use Oracle, where "writers never block readers" ;)

Comment: Is it possible that you change the dump options? If so, did you use `-extended-insert`? Then a `–extended-insert=FALSE` could help, but will slow down the import.

Comment: I use standart `mysql -u xxx xxx < my_table.dump`

Comment: `<`? This is an import. I mean the command when you dump the data to my_table.dump. Any chance that you use something like `mysqldump --opt`? That means you are using `--extended-insert` and `--add-locks` see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: oh!  no :) just `mysqldump -u ... -p ... db tabble > file` :)

Comment: Ahh, to quote from the manual:  `All of the options that --opt stands for also are on by default because --opt is on by default.` So when you add `–-extended-insert=FALSE` and `--add-locks=FALSE` to the mysqldump options your `select count(*)` should work (Untested, no mysql at hand). Depending on your situation beware of problems with the referential integrity of your db.

Comment: @Ocaso Protal, Great, this works! :)

Comment: Not exactly, as far as original question was about pausing and resuming sql. Anyway thank you very much and +1 :)

Comment: OK, your right (but it solved your problem)! Thanks for the +1! It's a pleasure to talk with you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not a way to suspend a query.

If you're doing bulk load work you might want to use a bulk loader that commits every few thousand rows.

Also, using MyISAM instead of InnoDB will alleviate this problem.  MyISAM is a good choice for bulk processing where you're not primarily concerned with transactional integrity.

Answer (score 2):

To quote from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html):

> All of the options that --opt stands for also are on by default
>   because --opt is on by default.

So when you add `–-extended-insert=FALSE` and `--add-locks=FALSE` to the mysqldump options your select count(*) should work. Depending on your situation beware of problems with the referential integrity of your db. And it will slow down the import!

Answer (score 0):

You can still get number of inserted records using `show innodb status`